# What are build 1.0 API in visual studio online? What they are used for?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In Team Services and TFS, a build request uses a build definition to add a new build to a build queue, and completed builds are assigned a build quality. With the Build (1.0) API, you can access each of these components.

**NOTE:** Build (2.0) is the updated and preferred API for these capabilities.

Comment: What do you think of my answer? Do you have problem?

Answer (score 0):

REST API for build 1.0 is used for [XAML build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181709(v=vs.120).aspx) and 2.0 version is used for XAML and [VNext builds](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview) (web-based)

You can set build quality to XAML build, not for vNext build.